# How to show WordPress admin dashboard forms on front-end?

Tags: admin, front-end

I need to show some WordPress Admin forms like "Dashboard > User > Add New User" or some parts from Woocommerce Admin like "Edit Product" on front-end without using any plugin(external plugins, I would prefer to create a plugin by myself)
How can I do it? Or Does it possible?

Comment: Why without a plugin? You'd need to write a plugin to do it anyway.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sorry, I meant without an external plugin. from WprdPress.org. I would like to create a plugin by myself. thanks